# Automatically Mute Windows on Shut Down

Tags: windows, audio

How can you automatically mute the audio in Windows every time you shut down?

Comment: Not sure I understand? If it's shut down, it's not going to make any noise anyway?

Comment: are you referring to trying to avoid the windows shutdown sounds?

Comment: I assume it is the problem I have had. I listen to music on my laptop at home. Bring it into the office and it starts playing. Windows brings the music player up long before the audio controls. Result: Battery removal.

Comment: To clarify, this is not about shut down sounds. This is about muting the sound on shut down. Tom Hawtin has it exactly right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[AutoMute](http://www.karpolan.com/software/auto-mute/) - a little portable program designed specifically for this. Automatically mutes on logoff, shutdown, so the next start up is quiet. Also enables a keyboard shortcut for quick quieting down.

[image]

Comment: Changing to this as the accepted answer because it's a simpler (albeit it 3rd party) solution.

Answer (score 7):

This is a bit of a hack, but here goes:

You can use [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) to do some useful things from the command line. One of these is muting the system audio. The command you'll need is:

```
nircmd.exe mutesysvolume 1
```

Put this line in a batch script, then [set it up](http://www.tutorial5.com/content/view/157/47/) as a [shutdown script](http://www.windows-help-central.com/windows-shutdown-script.html), so it will run every time you shut down.

Comment: NirCmd isn't built-in, isn't there something that is?

Comment: @dlamblin Not sure. There might be something in the registry somewhere though that stores this value.

Comment: The windows API is built in, but nothing inbuilt lets you change it progmaticly - nirCMD would be lighter than my idea of a quick python script :)

Answer (score 3):

To complement **lc**'s answer, I suggest that you create a WSH script, like the one below. Write the following code in Notepad, then save it as a `mute.vbs` file:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
For i=1 To 100
  WshShell.SendKeys(chr(&hAE))
Next
```

(based on an article found with Google at [nilpo.com](http://www.nilpo.com/2008/11/windows-xp/mute-sound-volume-in-wsh/))

The script turns the volume down to minimum (an alternative would be to mute the sound, with the `&hAD` code; that however would toggle the "muted" state, so unless you know how to check the "muted" state from the script, you couldn't be sure if the sound is off or on afterwards).

You should be able to register this script for Windows shutdown with the methods linked to by **lc** in his answer. (Note however, that on *Vista Home Premium* those are apparently unavailable).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean but you can turn off the shutdown noise in the "Sounds" Control Panel application

See here for how to do this
http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/accessibility/soundscheme.mspx

Comment: Haha. Note, "automatically."

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered, and I'm sure the solution works. Still, I'm posting because this possible solution which does not require any third party application. It is a bit drastic in that it shuts down the audio subsystem (driver) completely, not just muting the mixer.

Run a command prompt as administrator, and type the following:

```
net stop "Audiosrv"
```

to start the audio subsystem again, type the following:

```
net start "Audiosrv"
```

If you log off or sleep, this will work. A full shutdown/restart resets the audio back on.

The possible downside is some programs might display an error message when trying to play audio while the audio subsystem is disabled. (Winamp shows an annoying message box, while iTunes simply pauses peacefully.)

Answer (score 0):

You could just go into the control panel and remove the startup and shutdown sounds.  The exact procedure will vary somewhat by windows version, but on XP look for the "Sounds" tab in the "Sounds and Audio Devices" control panel icon.

Comment: I still want to have sound (so I can unmute it after boot-up if I'm in a 'Safe' location) - I just it to be muted on shut down.