# Samsung laptop unsafe volume warning?

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, audio

I have samsung laptop and usualy plugged into speakers which I can adjust, but since updating to windows 8.1 I keep noticing that every time I turn my laptop on while plugged into the speakers it automatically lowers and limits my volume to about 40% and when I try to turn it up a large banner warns me that any higher might be unsafe for my ears asking am I sure I want to do this. 
I searched on internet many people has same problem with samsung laptops.

How can I disable the unsafe volume warning?

Comment: Are you using a head phone?

Comment: [related](http://superuser.com/questions/191075/automatically-change-system-volume-when-audio-device-plugged-in)

Comment: I am not sure whethre [this](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/windows-reducing-system-volume/) works or not, but give it a try.

Comment: No, only speakers.

Comment: @Murat: Check msconfig and Task Manager - what Samsung programs and services are running at startup? One of them has to be responsible for this.