# Automatically adjust volume for audio jack vs. built in speakers?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio, speakers, headphones

Is there a setting to have my Windows 10 laptop automatically remember my volume settings when I plug in or unplug a device (speakers or headphones) into the 1/8" audio jack?

For instance, if I  plug in my headphones I would like it to revert the volume to whatever it was last time the headphones (or anything else) were plugged in; and when I unplug them I want it to switch to whatever it was before I plugged them in.

I have a Surface 3 which does exactly what I want, but my new Lenovo laptop doesn't.  Where can I turn this feature on?

---

Notes:

- I have looked at [this question](https://superuser.com/q/191075/455896), and it is asking basically the exact same thing, but it is also 5 years old and for Windows 7 and that answer doesn't seem to be applicable to Windows 10.
- I am not concerned about differentiating between different speakers or between speakers and headphones or anything like that, I just want it to remember one volume for the built-in speakers and one for anything plugged into the audio jack.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way I tested on Realtek audio drivers and laptop Lenovo b51-30 80lk. No realtek drivers will help you ever. You need to use Microsoft drivers that came with the OS. In driver details it needs to say Microsoft as Provider, not Realtek. Then you will have separate headphones and speaker volumes! Tested on Windows 10 20H2. No other solution worked. No advanced settings in **Realtek** app, no program **Ellp**, no powershell script by github user **PrateekKumarSingh**. Also prevent future automatic driver updates by Automatic Updates by disabling it in **gpedit** (`Computer Configuration -> Administrative templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Update -> Do not include drivers with Windows Updates: True`) or **System configuration** (disable services: `Background Intelligent Transfer Service`, `Windows Update`, and maybe `Windows Update Medic Service`). This may be risky because then you won't have automatic updates. It should look like this:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This was the solution for me, use the generic HD Audio drivers, not realtek

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out a solution based on the response to this question [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_devices/headphones-not-working-in-windows-10/7c172f44-52bf-4263-8b59-789e8f6cb3ae):

> I found another simple solution for this. If you have installed the Realtek software, open the Realtek HD Audio Manager , and check the " Disable front panel jack detection" option, under connector settings in the right side panel. The headphones and other audio devices work like a charm.

Although, when I went to the Realtek HD audio manager I had to click on "Device advanced settings" and then change the audio detector to "Multi-stream mode".  That instantly separated the audio outputs for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the only thing that worked was installing a way older version of the driver from 11. September 2017. It brought back the automatic switching between the two volume settings when plugging/unplugging my headphones. 
(Though I still can't open the Realtek HD Audio Manager)

The driver that worked for me: Realtek HD Audio-Treiber 6.0.1.8192 WHQL 11. September 2017:
https://www.computerbase.de/downloads/treiber/soundkarten/realtek-hd-audio-treiber/

Answer (score 0):

1. Open volume mixer (By right-clicking the volume icon on taskbar/tray)
2. You'll see Devices & applications. Under devices, you should see the active one - whether it's the headphones or the built-in speakers.
3. Click the active device icon, then a properties window will appear
4. Switch to the - probably - very next tab labeled 'levels' and adjust it to the desired volume
5. Repeat with plugging/unplugging the other device (You may be able to find all connected devices in volume mixer)

Answer (score -1):

I believe if the headphone Jack and the inbuilt speakers use different sound devices in windows, it will automatically remember the volume it was at last time it was used. (I know my several audio devices do on Windows 10).

It is essentially the same as the linked Windows 7 question that you put in the notes, in that if windows uses the same audio device for both, then you cannot do it.

Third party solution: get USB headphones, and it will remember the setting when you plug them in.

Answer (score -1):

I can confirm Windows 10 automatically (as far as I know) remembers the sound level settings for different devices. If I mute sound while headphones are connected, and then remove them, the sound returns.

Comment: It does that on one of my computers (A Surface 3), but not on my other one (A Lenovo Flex).  I am asking how to turn this feature on, not whether it exists.

Comment: Lenovo Yoga does not switch as well.

Comment: Lenovo Yoga 720 does not switch automatically, very annoying