# Windows - Auto-adjust volume when jack is plugged in/out

Tags: audio

I'm looking for a solution that could auto-adjust the sound volume when the output jack is plugged or not.

Typically, when I'm using jack output, I **always** set the volume to 80% (to external sound system) while when I'm using built-in speakers, I set the volume to a lower level.

I read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1105479/automatically-adjust-volume-for-audio-jack-vs-built-in-speakers) thread but it appears that on my laptop (Lenovo Y510p), the speakers and jack output are the same device and thus, Windows 10 cannot "remember" the volume levels.

So my question is: is there any tweaks to do that (from a Windows' parameter) or any software solution?

Comment: Might be a laptop-specific problem because mine does remember different levels between plugged and not-plugged states.  When you plug something in to the headphone jack, do you get a notification from Windows about it?

Comment: No notification, I guess its normal since it doesn't see any difference between jack output and speaker. However, following some links, I found out that uninstalling the realtek (my soundcard vendor) driver and letting Windows installing its own (generic?) driver works sometimes (in the way that after that, two sound devices are referenced). I'll try it out tonight and edit the question following the result.